# Customize scrollbar height for Firefox

Tags: css

So, I have this website where I can use a horizontal scroll, to customize the scrollbar's `height`, I'm using this:

```css
.someElement {
  /* content */
}

.someElement::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
}
```

This will make the scrollbar have the height of `5px`. But for Firefox, how do I do it?

For the vertical one, of course the easiest or maybe the only way to do it of course is this:

```css
.someElement {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

but I'm talking about horizontal here.

Comment: Your code should be fine as it is. `scrollbar-width` works for both vertical and horizontal scrollbars.